# Need Second Set of Eyes on C# Code

Tags: c#, debugging, subclass, tostring, gettype

I have been looking over this for a couple of hours and cannot find the reason why nothing is being output. No errors are indicated so its something within the actual code. Can someone please look this over and possibly catch something I'm not seeing?  Thanks!

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Tape
    {
        public Tape(int length, int width)
        {
            len = length;
            wid = width;
        }
        public int len { get; set; }
        public int wid { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\nLength: {1}\nWidth: {2}", GetType(), len, wid);
        }
    }

    class VideoTape : Tape
    {
        public int PlayTime { get; set; }
        public VideoTape(int length, int width, int playTime)
            : base(len, wid)
        {
            PlayTime = playTime;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\nPlay Time: {1}", base.ToString(), PlayTime);
        }
    }
    class AdhesiveTape : Tape
    {
        private int _stickiness;
        public AdhesiveTape(int length, int width, int stickiness)
            : base(length, width)
        {
            Stickiness = stickiness;
        }
        public int Stickiness
        {
            get { return _stickiness; }
            set
            {
                if (value >= 1 && value <= 10)
                    _stickiness = value;
                else
                    _stickiness = 0;
            }
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\nStickiness: {1}",
                base.ToString(), (Stickiness == 0) ? "Invalid Input" : Stickiness.ToString());
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tape = new Tape(100, 10);
            var videoTape = new VideoTape(50, 5, 200);
            var adhesiveTape = new AdhesiveTape(500, 8, 8);

            Console.WriteLine(tape);
            Console.WriteLine(videoTape);
            Console.WriteLine(adhesiveTape);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a compile error for `:base(len, wid)`, it should be `base(length, width)`

Comment: @YacoubMassad I'm not sure that's a compiler error, since VideoTape inherits from Tape and `len` and `wid` are valid fields in that class, but it's almost certainly a typo.

Comment: Okay, I had to paste the code into my own VS, but yeah, in that context the `len` and `wid` fields would have to be static in order to work in that context, so it is indeed a compile error. Strange that OP isn't seeing those errors, though. How are you (OP) compiling this code?

Comment: @Abion47 yes both Michal and Yacoub are right. This line needs, : base(len, wid), needs to change since those parameters are not in in the constructor.

Comment: Can you find a rubber duck? If so, try using Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated before, there is a parameter passing problem in the VideoTape type's constructor calling the base constructor, the following code works fine for me:

```
    using System;
    namespace ConsoleApplication8
    {
        class Tape
        {
            public Tape(int length, int width)
            {
                len = length;
                wid = width;
            }
            public int len { get; set; }
            public int wid { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0}\nLength: {1}\nWidth: {2}", GetType(), len, wid);
            }
        }

        class VideoTape : Tape
        {
            public int PlayTime { get; set; }
            public VideoTape(int length, int width, int playTime)
                : base(length, width)
            {
                PlayTime = playTime;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0}\nPlay Time: {1}", base.ToString(), PlayTime);
            }
        }
        class AdhesiveTape : Tape
        {
            private int _stickiness;
            public AdhesiveTape(int length, int width, int stickiness)
                : base(length, width)
            {
                Stickiness = stickiness;
            }
            public int Stickiness
            {
                get { return _stickiness; }
                set
                {
                    if (value >= 1 && value <= 10)
                        _stickiness = value;
                    else
                        _stickiness = 0;
                }
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0}\nStickiness: {1}",
                    base.ToString(), (Stickiness == 0) ? "Invalid Input" : Stickiness.ToString());
            }
        }

        class Test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var tape = new Tape(100, 10);
                var videoTape = new VideoTape(50, 5, 200);
                var adhesiveTape = new AdhesiveTape(500, 8, 8);

                Console.WriteLine(tape);
                Console.WriteLine(videoTape);
                Console.WriteLine(adhesiveTape);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Changed:

```
    public VideoTape(int length, int width, int playTime)
            : base(len, wid)
```

To:

```
    public VideoTape(int length, int width, int playTime)
            : base(length, width)
```

The len and wid are not parameters of the VideoTape constructor, thus can not be passed to the base constructor

Here is a .net fiddle where you can see it running and play around with it:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/YZUC4O

Comment: Perhaps in your answer you may want to point the OP to the exact issue and what you fixed and why your fix works. Otherwise other people will need to find the fix in all that code you have pasted.

Comment: After changing the code on my end, I still received no output.  I changed it exactly as you have.